# react.js как вставить блок в середине цикла map?

Tags: javascript, массивы, json, reactjs, map

Всем привет, я очень новичёк в реакт и столкнулся с такой задачей:

У меня есть 5 блоков с данными, которые я вывожу в цикле.

Но я не могу понять, как мне добавить в середину совершенно другой блок. Данные для карточек я загружаю из json, потом через .map передаю данные для каждого отдельного блока.

Буду крайне признателен за помощь в этом вопросе!

```
renderBeds() {
    return this.state.beds.map((bed, index) => {
        return (
            <Bed
                key={index}
                bed={bed}
            />
        )
    })
};
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы решил таким способом

```js
render() {
  const {beds} = this.state;
  return (
    <>
      {beds
        .slice(0, 2)
        .map((bed, index) => {
          return (
            <Bed
              key={bed.id}
              bed={bed}
            />
          )
        })
       }
       <Divider />
      {beds
        .slice(2)
        .map((bed, index) => {
          return (
            <Bed
              key={bed.id}
              bed={bed}
            />
          )
         })
        }
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе, мил человек! А скажи пожалуйста, почему ты для key используешь bed.id, а не index ?

Comment: Вообще не стоит использовать index как key. Это, своего рода, антипатерн react.

Comment: странно, я видел такую штуку в документации :/

Comment: Мы не рекомендуем использовать индексы как ключи, если порядок элементов может поменяться. Это негативно скажется на производительности и может вызвать проблемы с состоянием компонента. Это из оф документации